Google sheets equivalent of Explode in python?
I have a table with one of the columns containing a list of comma delimited values in google sheets. How  do I transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values.
Python equivalent function explode function: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html
As an explample, here is the input table:-



A
B




1
P, Q


2
Q



Desired output:-



A
B




1
P


1
Q


2
Q




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-explode+google-sheets pick your choice

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/first-normal-form+google-sheets
